# SSL certificate for client

Tags: ssl, https

I have a webserver where a SSL certificate is installed.
The webserver only responds to https calls.

When going to the website with an ordinary browser everything works fine. The certificate has been provided by Verisign, so the browsers don't complain.

But when I want to go to the site with something else, like curl or wget, how am I supposed to authenticate?
If I write

```
curl https://example.com --insecure
```

then it works. But what if I want to present a valid certificate and remove the "insecure" flag? Where should I get one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably misunderstanding. It's not curl which is presenting a certificate to the server. It's the server presenting its certificate to the client, and the client being unable to verify it. Using the `--insecure` option makes the client ignore the validity of the presented certificate and continue regardless.

To verify and trust a certificate the client needs to have the signer's root certificate in its local trust store. Meaning, curl needs Verisign's root certificate somewhere in its list of certificates it checks against. That list is probably different from the list the browser uses, hence the difference. How exactly to update curls list depends on your exact system; you may want to open a new question about how to do this in detail.